# Telescoping Series Sequence Question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

A sequence $a_n$ of real numbers is defined recursively by $a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac {a_n}{a_n + 1}$; $a_1 = 1$. I have already proved that $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} = \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{(a_n+1)(a_{n+1}+1)}$, $1 \leq a_n \leq 2$, and $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq 2 \cdot 4^{-n}$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$. And the limit $l$ $= \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Question: By considering the telescoping series formula $\sum_{k=n}^\infty{a_{k+1}-a_k} = a_{n+1}-l$, deduce that $|a_{n+1}-l| \leq \frac{2}{3} \cdot 4^{-(n-1)}$.

I am not sure how to do this question. From the telescoping series, is it true that $l = a_{n+1} + a_n$??

Comment: use triangle inequality

Comment: @QED Using what terms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\left| a_{n+1} - l \right| \le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty | a_k - a_{k+1} | \le \sum_{k=n+1}2\times 4^{-k}
$$

Comment: where does this inequality come from. I can't see why the first one is true ?

Comment: $| a_{n+1} - l | = \left| \sum_{k = n + 1}  a_k - a_{k+1} \right|   \le \sum_{k = n + 1}\left|   a_k - a_{k+1} \right|$ @NikitaMazepin

Comment: How do we get from this to the desired inequality then ?